# ListView with multiple kinds of layouts

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

My situation is as following. I have two layouts

First:

```
<RelativeLayout ... >
    <TextView id="@+id/textview1" .../>
    <TextView id="@+id/textview2" .../>
    <ImageView .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Second:

```
<RelativeLayout ... >
    <TextView id="@+id/textview3" .../>
    <TextView id="@+id/textview4" .../>
    <ImageView .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I'm gonna to make a listview with these two layouts. The ArrayAdapter is ready. Now I need to create a new instance of the adapter and I'm stuck here. Cause its constructor is:

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, 
    int resource, 
    int textViewResourceId, 
    List<T> objects)

context     The current context.
resource    The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
textViewResourceId  The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated
objects     The objects to represent in the ListView.
```

**Problem & Question**:
I don't know how to deal with the second and the third parameters. It seems each of the two parameters has multiple choices. How can I initiate the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make your own Adapter, maybe extends from BaseAdapter and implement the getView() method, change your layout depending on each item you want. Check this piece of code, this may helps:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> data){
        this.data = data;
        //This is your data from outside

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            if(condition for layout 1){
                // inflate layout 1 to your view here
                            // import data from data.get(position) into you view here
            }else if(condition for layout 2){
                // inflate layout 2 for your view here
                            // import data from data.get(position) into you view here
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Basic things are always forgotten easily. Thank you!